# Updating a broken dependency module-info.java without recompiling it?

Tags: java, logback, java-module, java-platform-module-system, module-info

My code depends on Logback which seems to have [a bug](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/pull/501) in its `module-info.java` file. The author seems to be indisposed for an extended period of time. Is there a way for me to patch this dependency's `module-info.java` file without having to recompile and depend on a forked version?

Comment: Based on the bug, how about using an explicit VM arg `--add-reads ch.qos.logback.classic=java.logging`?

Comment: @Naman That did it. Thank you! Please post a formal answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: I assume ch.qos.logback.classic wasn't compiled as a module, as this would have been caught at compile-time. Maybe they compiled the module-info.java separately but didn't test it.